# cannot display a button control in infopath form

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

My problem is that: when In create a form with Infopath 2010 and I add a button control, the button does not appear when I open it in display mode. then I decide to add the button in the ribbon with sharepoint designer 2010 but this button appear only in the default display form. please I need someone help me to solve this problem. I'm new in sharepoint
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the stock button control built into InfoPath?  If you are not, the button images need to be uploaded and checked in within the SharePoint site.  InfoPath forms should display stock buttons out of the box with no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When using picture buttons, head to the picture button properties and deselect the option that says 'Hide picture button in read-only views'.